# WordPress : REST API plugin to extract featured image URL

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I've installed the WordPress REST API plugin on a blog and I want to use it to pull content from the blog posts into a panel window within another website. Text content is fine, but I'm not sure about getting the "Featured image" URL. I want the URL so I can store it within a variable and then use it as the background image CSS of the panel (that displays blog data in the panel window of the NON-WORDPRESS site).

Here is an example of the data feed that is returned (just the first entry):

```
[{
    "id": 15470,
    "date": "2015-05-21T15:56:31",
    "date_gmt": "2015-05-21T05:56:31",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/?p=15470"
    },
    "modified": "2016-06-06T10:01:53",
    "modified_gmt": "2016-06-06T00:01:53",
    "slug": "test-post-3",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/2015\/05\/21\/test-post-3\/",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "test post"
    },
    "content": {
        "rendered": "<p>[slideshow_deploy id=&#8217;15471&#8242;]<\/p>\n<p>WP REST API plugins is great for getting your blog content out into another website.<\/p>\n<div id=\"attachment_15405\" style=\"width: 160px\" class=\"wp-caption alignleft\"><a href=\"http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/files\/2014\/08\/Hotel-Metropole-Thursday-Island-1897.jpg\" rel=\"attachment wp-att-15405\"><img class=\"size-thumbnail wp-image-15405\" src=\"http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/files\/2014\/08\/Hotel-Metropole-Thursday-Island-1897-150x150.jpg\" alt=\"Hotel Metropole, Thursday Island, 1897\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\" \/><\/a><p class=\"wp-caption-text\">Hotel Metropole, Thursday Island, 1897<\/p><\/div>\n"
    },
    "excerpt": {
        "rendered": "<p>[slideshow_deploy id=&#8217;15471&#8242;] WP REST API plugins is great for getting your blog content out into another website.<\/p>\n"
    },
    "author": 11,
    "featured_media": 15392,
    "comment_status": "open",
    "ping_status": "open",
    "sticky": false,
    "format": "standard",
    "categories": [1],
    "tags": [],
    "_links": {
        "self": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/15470"
        }],
        "collection": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts"
        }],
        "about": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types\/post"
        }],
        "author": [{
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users\/11"
        }],
        "replies": [{
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/comments?post=15470"
        }],
        "version-history": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/15470\/revisions"
        }],
        "https:\/\/api.w.org\/featuredmedia": [{
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media\/15392"
        }],
        "https:\/\/api.w.org\/attachment": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media?parent=15470"
        }],
        "https:\/\/api.w.org\/term": [{
            "taxonomy": "category",
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories?post=15470"
        }, {
            "taxonomy": "post_tag",
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/tags?post=15470"
        }]
    }
}]
```

Now I can see the entry for the featured image being:

```
"featured_media": 15392,
```

Then further down below under the '_links' object there is these several lines:

```
"https:\/\/api.w.org\/featuredmedia": [{
    "embeddable": true,
    "href": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media\/15392"
}],
```

When I try to use that URL, it obviously just pulls back another JSON feed, and then it seems to pull back the actual featured image URL as:

```js
"guid": {
    "rendered": "http:\/\/blog2.slq.qld.gov.au\/jol\/files\/2014\/08\/NT-app2.png"
},
```

When that path can be converted into a proper URL, then I can store it as variable and use it. What is happening here? Is this like a JSON feed within another JSON feed?

How could I extract the featured image URL out? I am familiar with building HTML content from a JSON feed where everything is available from the parent feed but I am not familiar with this pattern.

Comment: Yep. This API is soooo bloated. Did you ever figure out a good way to do this?